# Pass info from plot to function

Tags: python, graph-tool

I want to write interactive simulation using graph-tool. What I would like to do is first to visualize the graph, then pick nodes as an input for later actual simulation. How do I pass information from plot to function?

What I did so far - I looked through documentation and examples which do not provide such info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke [`graph_draw`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw) with `output` parameter set to `None` (which is the default), it returns a:

> Boolean-valued vertex property map marking the vertices which were
>   selected interactively.

If `output` is not given, the graph "will be displayed via [`interactive_window()`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.interactive_window)" whose documentation points to [`GraphWidget`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.GraphWidget) for key bindings information:

> A group of vertices may be selected by holding the “shift” button
>   while the pointer is dragged while pressing the left button.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import graph_tool.all as gt

points = np.random.random((25, 2))
g, pos = gt.geometric_graph(points, 0.3)
_, selected = gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos)
print(*selected.a)
```

Outputs:

```
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```